# Kotlin native run JavaScript

Tags: encryption, kotlin, webview, kotlin-native

I was wondering if there was any way to run JS encrypted websites in a Kotlin native environment.

Let's just say that I want to get something off the internet, and it's protected, it's website's source code changes from day to day and I can't update the website decryption daily.

Is there a way to run a website in native kotlin? I know you can do it in Android kotlin(JVM) as android sdk includes WebView which can run in the background.

Would there be a way to do it consistently over any platform?